# Beamer proof with comment

Tags: beamer, theorems

In the following MWE, the comment [to be known] for the proof environment makes the "proof" word disappear, while there is no problem with definition, theorem...

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usetheme{Madrid}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{definition}[don't forget it !]
        this is a definition
    \end{definition}

    \begin{theorem}[very important !]
        this is a theorem
    \end{theorem}

    \begin{proof}[to be known]
        and this is the proof!
    \end{proof}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could redefine the proof environment:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usetheme{Madrid}

  \renewenvironment<>{proof}[1][\proofname]{%
    \par
    \def\insertproofname{Proof (#1)}%
    \pushQED{\qed}
    \usebeamertemplate{proof begin}#2}
  {\popQED\usebeamertemplate{proof end}}

  \newenvironment<>{emptyproof}[1][\proofname]{%
    \par
    \def\insertproofname{Proof}%
    \pushQED{\qed}
    \usebeamertemplate{proof begin}#2}
  {\popQED\usebeamertemplate{proof end}}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{definition}[don't forget it !]
        this is a definition
    \end{definition}

    \begin{theorem}[very important !]
        this is a theorem
    \end{theorem}

    \begin{proof}[to be known]
        and this is the proof!
    \end{proof}

    \begin{emptyproof}
        and this is the proof!
    \end{emptyproof}    
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your solution gives "Proof (proof)" when I use it without comment.
I should add something like "if there's no #1 then..." but I don't know how to do it with latex.

Comment: @Romain Please see my edit